# Synchronizing with upstream and generating clean patches in Git

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

What is the recommended way to synchronize a git repo with upstream?

*Let's say my work is based of SVN branch A in upstream. They have moved to branch B, and C.
I want to synchronize my work with upstream now. Should I merge, pull, rebase, cherry pick?*

What is the recommended way to create a clean patch against upstream?

*Should I just diff? Or should I rebase and then squash?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use git-svn and get branch B and C.

If you want your work on top of B or C, rebase on top of those.

```
git checkout branchA
git rebase --onto branchB origin/BranchA # replace branchB with branchC if you want
```

What do you mean by "clean" patch against upstream?

You should rebase. It's up to you if you want to squash.

Comment: Fine, rebase, but what next? I make a copy of my stable branch, rebase it and then merge back into stable?

Comment: depends on the workflow. If you are to share it, then commit to SVN with git-svn. If it has to be used on yet another branch, yes you can merge it.

Comment: The SVN is upstream. I'm maintaining a fork.

Comment: Then just push it to where others can see it? github? unfuddle?

Comment: I have a public repository with a stable branch. I want to sync my repository with upstream. I can't "just push".